# How to identify lag variable based on a pre-defined sequence

Tags: r, time-series, tidyverse

I have a time series where I want to generate a new variable that is equal to the value of a variable `value` in the previous year.

My problem is that for the initial year of the time series I get NAs when I generate the lagged variable. The content of `value` follows a repeating pattern, but that pattern is different by `id`.

In theory, one should be able to pattern match the observed sequence of `value` and use the known pattern to fill in the NAs in the lagged variable, but I can't figure out how to approach this problem.

I tried joining the pattern sequence to data, and cast it wide so I had three new columns for each of the elements of the sequence. I was thinking I might be able to somehow loop through columns based on the value in the last year with data. But because of the nature of the sequence I realized I'd need to pattern match on the entire sequence, not just one value at a time.

```
data <- tibble(
  year=rep(2015:2018,3),
  id=c(rep('A',4),rep('B',4),rep('C',4)),
  value=c('CG','SB','CG','CG',
          'CG','CG','CG','CG',
          'CG','SB','CG','SB')
)

data.seq <- tibble(
  seq1=c('CG','CG','SB'),
  seq2=c('CG','CG',NA),
  seq3=c('CG','SB',NA)
)

# Generate new variable that has 'value' of previous year
data <- data %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(
    lagValue = lag(value)
  )

# Need to fill in the NA's based on the sequences in data.seq
```

To help answer the question, I've manually entered what the output should be for the NAs given the sequences in `data.seq`:

```
expected.data <- data
expected.data[c(1,5,9),'lagValue'] <- c('CG','CG','SB')
```

Comment: Can you post the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

I have created a kind of sort function for your use.

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- tibble(
  year = rep(2015:2018, 3),
  id = c(rep('A', 4), rep('B', 4), rep('C', 4)),
  value = c(
    'CG',
    'SB',
    'CG',
    'CG',
    'CG',
    'CG',
    'CG',
    'CG',
    'CG',
    'SB',
    'CG',
    'SB'
  )
)

# lookup list for ids and sequence
data.seq <- list()
data.seq$A <- c('CG', 'CG', 'SB')
data.seq$B <- c('CG', 'CG')
data.seq$C <- c('CG', 'SB')


findPos <- function(value, group) {

  # select sequence according to group
  currentSeq <- data.seq[[unique(group)]]

  # get rid of NAs
  seqMatch <- currentSeq[!is.na(currentSeq)]

  # multiplier for sequence
  compareLength <- length(value) + length(seqMatch) - 1

  multi <- compareLength / length(seqMatch)
  mod <- compareLength %% length(seqMatch)

  if (mod > 0) {
    multi <- as.integer(multi) + 1

  }

  # multiple sequence
  seqMatch <- rep(seqMatch, multi)

  i <- 1
  # search und rotate position until match is found
  repeat {
    if (identical(lag(value)[!is.na(lag(value))], 
                  seqMatch[i:(length(value) - 2 + i)])) {

      # if found on first position, add another sequence at the beginning
      if (length(seqMatch[i - 1]) == 0) {
        return(c(currentSeq, seqMatch)[length(currentSeq)+i-1])

      } else {
        return(seqMatch[i - 1])
      }

    }

    i <- i + 1

  }

}

data <- data %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(lagValue = ifelse(is.na(lag(value)), 
                           findPos(value, id), 
                           lag(value)))
```

Comment: Thanks @Patrick. I think this is an interesting approach. The only thing that might not work is that in my real data the number of unique ID values is in the hundreds. So the `seqMatch` variable that manually selects sequence according to group would be hard to implement for the whole data. Do you have any thoughts on how to convert that to an automated selection?

Comment: It depends on how you could provide the IDs and the according sequence. I updated my example with a lookup list and a more steady version of the sequence match. You could also go on with a nested tibble for the IDs and the sequence.